# same javascript file, but different file size depends on a server?

Tags: http-headers, gzip

I have a weird problem.

I have two exact website on two servers - dev and qa.

The dev one shows that my javascript size is 100kb, but the qa says 400kb. When I save the script on my local, it is 400kb.

I looked at the header of the javascript on the dev and it looks like..it's sending

```
"Content-Encoding   gzip".
```

What is this and how do I enable this on the qa to make my script smaller?

Comment: It's compression.  How you enable it depends on what web server you're running, could you provide that information?

Comment: @ShaneMadden // I'm running ubunt.

Comment: That's your OS, on top of which there are a myriad of options for HTTP servers.  Do you know which one you use?

Comment: @ShaneMadden // ah! I'm using apache.  I think I found a link. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html is that correct one? and...please make a new post...I like choose your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should mostly just be a matter of making sure that your modules and settings match between the two servers.

Run `a2enmod deflate` on the server that's not compressing to make sure the module's enabled, then check to be sure the configurations match (server config in `apache2.conf`, site config in `sites-available`, and module config in `mods-available/deflate.conf`), do a `service apache2 restart` to apply any changes, and you should see compression behave the same across the servers.